# Azure Bicep Modules: Can modules be referenced from a separate repo?

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-pipelines, azure-bicep

## Functioning Code Using Terraform

I am more familiar with Terraform, where I can do something like:

```
module "storagemod" {
  source = "git::https://MyProj@dev.azure.com/MyProj/Dataplatform/_git/myrepo//storage-account?ref=v0.2.0"
  rg_name = "MyRG"
  resource_name = "mynewdatalake"
  .
  .
  .
}
```

where the `source` referenced above is a *different* repository of Terraform modules that I am referencing to create resources.

The repository is a *private* Azure repository (on Azure DevOps) that I am able to access because I have already established git credentials in a previous step of the pipeline:

```yaml
steps:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    inputs:
      targetType: inline
      script: 'git config --global http.extraheader "AUTHORIZATION: bearer ${Env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN}"'
    displayName: 'Setting Git Authentication header'
    env:
      SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
```

## How to Do This in Bicep?

How could I do something similar using Azure Bicep?  We are trying to move over to Bicep.

I can do the same authentication of the Git headers, of course, but how can I handle the module?

#### Local

If it were local on the same repo, I could do:

```
module storagemod './storage/datalake.bicep' = {
  name: 'createDataLakeAndContainers'
  params: {
    .
    .
    .
  }
}
```

#### Separate Repo

Can I do something like this?

```
module storagemod 'git::https://MyProj@dev.azure.com/MyProj/Dataplatform/_git/myrepo//storage-account?ref=v0.2.0' = {
  name: 'createDataLakeAndContainers'
  params: {
    .
    .
    .
  }
}
```

I couldn't get that to work, but I was hoping that the capability is there and I just had the syntax wrong.  I could not find any documentation on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not possible in Bicep (yet).

There are two open issues in bicep's github that addresses this issue:

- https://github.com/Azure/bicep/issues/660
- https://github.com/Azure/bicep/issues/2128

For now only way is to use either git submodules or maintain "remote" bicep files using some custom solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response and detailed references!  Too bad its not ready, but at least now I am subscribed to the issues.  :)

Comment: bicep registry is planned for 0.5 release which I think will be released in September. stay tuned!